# How to create NFC tag that contains NDEF data?

Tags: iphone, nfc, ios11, lib-nfc, open-nfc

Recently, Apple has opened NFC for iPhone 7. I have been experimenting this feature. I don't know how to create NFC tags which contain NDEF data. If anyone knows, please share your knowledge

Comment: Did you manage to show/expose NFC data from the iPhone?, as far as I know you can only 'read' NDEF data from not iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the devices you have at hand; there are Android apps, like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter&hl=de or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ndeftools.boilerplate -  obviously you need an Android phone with NFC functionality for that.
Or you could use desktop-based tools, like http://ndefeditor.grundid.de/ or https://github.com/skjolber/nfc-eclipse-plugin
In this case you have to use a contactless reader.

Comment: The Eclipse plugin also works using an Android device